# Encoding issue while using wikipedia table scraper

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to import the tables from Wikipedia page to Pandas, however, I am facing multiple encoding issues and have no clue how to solve them.

```
import wikipedia as wp
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

wiki_page = 'Climate_of_Italy'
html = wp.page(wiki_page).html()

def dataframe_cleaning(table_number=int):
    global html
    df = pd.read_html(html, encoding='utf-8')[table_number]
    df.drop(np.arange(5, len(df.index)), inplace=True)
    df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()
    
    find = '\((.*?)\)'
    for i, column in enumerate(df.columns):
        if i>0:
            df[column] = df[column].replace(u'\u2212', '-')
            df[column] = (df[column]
                          .str.findall(find)
                          .map(lambda x: np.round((float(x[0])-32)* (5/9), 2)))
    return df

florence_df = dataframe_cleaning(6)
florence_df
```

The current error I am getting is:

`ValueError: could not convert string to float: '−9.8'`

I understand that `'−' != '-'`, however, I cannot replace the following symbol no matter how much I try. I attempted to use Pandas directly with `pd.read_html()`, but then faced the similar issue.

I know it might be a simple question, but I cannot wrap my head around on how to fix it.

Thank you in advance!

### Update:

The question has been answered, but @baduker also pointed out that the replacement can be done directly on the html:

```
import wikipedia as wp
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

wiki_page = 'Climate_of_Italy'
html = wp.page(wiki_page).html().replace(u'\u2212', '-')
```

Did not know that the following option is available. Believe that this is much nicer as it can be executed a single time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df[column].replace(u'\u2212', '-')
```

This replaces only if the entire value is exactly `u'\u2212'`. You want to use `df[column].str.replace` instead.

Comment: The greatest facepalm moment. Thank you very much! I was so focused on a bigger problems that I completely forgot about little things haha